# Code Signing an Automator Workflow file within macOS app bundle

Tags: macos, app-store, app-store-connect, mac-app-store, appstore-sandbox

I am attempting to upload a macOS binary to the Mac App Store via the Xcode Organizer.

I get an "Upload failed" error with the message:

> App Store Connect Operation Error
>
> **ERROR ITMS-90276**: Missing Bundle Identifier. The application bundle contains a tool or framework workflow [`com.company.AppName.pkg/Payload/AppName.app/Contents/Resources/Resources/Scripts/workflow.workflow`] that is missing the bundle identifier in its Info.plist file.

My app bundle contains `AppleScript.scpt`, `ShellScript.sh`, and `workflow.workflow` scripting files.

What kind of scripts need Info.plist and Bundle Identifiers for signing? How can I get past this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple requires that all bundled executables be code signed

> #### What to Code Sign
>
> You sign all the individual components of your app, leaving no gaps, including:
>
> **Nested code.** First, you recursively sign all of the **helpers, tools,** libraries, frameworks, and other components that your app relies on, and that are bundled with your app.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Procedures/Procedures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH4-SW2

In this case, the `workflow.workflow` Automator Workflow bundle is failing code signature because it is missing a Bundle Identifier in its existing Info.plist.

I added the lines:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.company.AppName.SampleWorkflow</string>
```

after adding the BundleID, the Xcode Organizer signs and uploads to the Mac App Store without issue.